# Make links based on textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I have something like a search bar, but instead of searching, it appends the text box contents to an address.

For example say I type in "hello", I'd like to have a button bellow which links to "https://example.com/hello".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be something as simple as below, you get the value of the text on a button click, and then when you have clicked the button you append the value of the text box to the end of a domain which can be whatever you want it to be

To redirect on the button click you can add...

`window.location.replace(url)` where the `p.innerText` is.

```js
var search = document.querySelector('#search');
var button = document.querySelector('#search-btn');
var p = document.querySelector('p');
var url;

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  url = 'exampledomain.com/' + search.value;
  
  p.innerText = url;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" />
<button id="search-btn">Search</button>
<p></p>
```